# How to replicate a plot of means for a 2 by 3 by 4 design in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a graph that I did in SPSS

[image]

I would like to replicate this in R.

The data file is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/sendergraphR.csv

UPDATE:

I've figured out how to to it for the other graph:

```
graph2<-read.csv(file="SendergraphR.csv")
ddr <- recast(graph2,no.GREEN+no.RED+Senderidentity~variable,
    fun.aggregate=mean,id.var=c("no.GREEN","no.RED","Senderidentity"))

qplot(x=no.GREEN,y=Mean_Message,data=ddr,colour=Senderidentity, 
    group=Senderidentity,geom="line")+facet_wrap(~no.RED,ncol=1)
```

Now what I would like to do is to separate this second graph into two columns one looking at the cases where the variable urn1 is blue and the other where its red: here's a graph of how it should look:

[image]

I was thinking of doing it the following way:

```
ddr <- recast(graph2,no.GREEN+no.RED+Senderidentity+urn1~variable,
    fun.aggregate=mean,id.var=c("no.GREEN","no.RED","Senderidentity", "urn1"))
qplot(x=no.GREEN,y=Mean_Message,data=ddr,colour=Senderidentity, group=Senderidentity,geom="line")+facet_wrap(~no.RED,ncol=1) +
    facet_wrap(~urn1, ncol=2)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are two problems here. One to calculate the mean probabilities and means, another to plot the results. First problem requires some model, which you do not specify. So it is hard to help you, since we need to guess the model. The second should be easy to do, using ggplot2. Please supply the response variables of your models, then it would be possible to recreate these graphs.

Comment: @mpiktas on the graph Mean probability of guessing RED is just a bad way of looking at the variable DecisionasReceiver. Basically we're interested in how many chose 1 under different conditions. Similarly on the second graph Mean message just means how many people chose 1 in the DecisionasSender variable. Both datasets contain all the information. Here's how I did it SPSS: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/graphforreceiver.tiff

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/sender-graph.tiff These should give you an idea of how its set up. The dataset is the same. THanks!

Comment: at this point this seems not to be a statistics question--- migrate to SO R tag?

Comment: @john, yep this should be migrated. Voting to close.

Comment: I would suggest to keep this question here as it already got valiant follow-up and an accepted answer (not that I don't want to close or migrate the 4th Rish post of the day).

Comment: @Daniel, please revert this to the previous question, and ask the new question separately, linking to this one. Also please see the FAQ and properly format the code, now it has an error in it. The answer to your second question is very simple, but you must figure it out by yourself. This site is for learning, not for getting your job done by somebody else. If somebody does not show inclination to learn (as you do), there is no incentive to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more or less standard ggplot2 problem. So I will only give an idea how to reproduce this graph. First get the data

```
dd<-structure(list(no.GREEN=c(1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L),no.RED=c(5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,7L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L),Messagereceived=structure(c(2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L),.Label=c("blue","red"),class="factor"),Decisionasreceivercode=c(0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L),OptimalResponse=c(1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L)),.Names=c("no.GREEN","no.RED","Messagereceived","Decisionasreceivercode","OptimalResponse"),class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,-328L))
```

Then transform it to get the desired statistics:

```
ddr<-recast(dd,no.GREEN+no.RED+Messagereceived~variable,fun.aggregate=mean,id.var=c("no.GREEN","no.RED","Messagereceived"))
```

And finaly plot it:

```
qplot(x=no.GREEN,y=Decisionasreceivercode,data=ddr,colour=no.RED,group=no.RED,geom="line")+facet_wrap(~Messagereceived,ncol=1)
```

The result will be the following:

[image]

I will leave the second graph and the cleaning up of the first one as an exercise :)

**Update:** There is alternative cleaner way to get the aggregation:

```
ddr<-aggregate(dd$Decision,by=as.list(dd[,1:3]),mean)
```

We lose the name of the variable this way, but save some time with not typing three names two times.

Comment: What? You're not doing _all_ his work for him? +1 for that (well, that and the excellent answer)!

Comment: @mpiktas thank you very much! there definitely remains quite a few things to clean up, but this is an excellent lead. My only remaining question is how I can add an additional line with the Optimal variable plotted. thanks again

Comment: @mpiktas I'm trying to reproduce the graph to have only 1,2,3,4 in the bottom. I've added xlim(1,4) but it won't change it, what am I missing?

Comment: @Daniel, I suggest to  read  ggplot2 book. `xlim` only sets the limits, they are fine here. What you want is to change the type of variable. `qplot` assumes that `no.GREEN` is numeric, hence it produces numeric axis. Try changing it to factor and then inspect the results.

Comment: @mpiktas I do want to read the ggplot2 book in the future, but currently I do not have it. I could only download the chapter relating to qplot but it didn't really detail what I should do. I've tried changing it to numeric by adding .class="numeric"but an error always comes up like Error: unexpected ',' in "L,"

Comment: @mpiktas I managed to replicate the other graph which is great, now the only problem remaining is how to get change them to numeric and how to add the optimal lines on top of these. I would really appreciate your help as it's quite urgent

Comment: You want `no.GREEN` as a factor, not a numeric.  `ddr$no.GREEN <- factor(ddr$no.GREEN)`.

Comment: @Aaron thanks so much for your help! this is what happened:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/RPlot.pdf

Comment: I suspect you're not using the aggregated data.  If it's something else, you'll need a ggplot expert to help you there, sorry.

Comment: @Aaron it works pretty well now thanks! but I still don't know how to fit the extra line. can someone help? also what am I doing wrong with this? colors<-c("#000000","#F8766D","#7CAE00")
> d+scale_fill_manual(values=colors)

Comment: Treat the extra line just like another no.Red; you'll have to reshape your data using `cast` and `melt`.  There are plenty of questions here (and on SO) that you should be able to fine.

Comment: @Aaron see my updated question.

Comment: One question per question, please.  Better to revert this one to how it was and start a new one, linking back to this one.  If you do, stackoverflow.com is probably a better place for questions specifically about R.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the `lattice` library:

A simple version (not shown):

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Decisionasreceivercode ~ factor(no.GREEN) | Messagereceived,
       group=no.RED, type="a", data=dd)
```

Or with better labeling:

```
names(dd)[3] <- 'Message Received'
xyplot(Decisionasreceivercode ~ factor(no.GREEN) | `Message Received`,
       group=no.RED, type="a", xlab="No. Green",
       ylab="Decision as Receiver Code",
       strip=strip.custom(strip.names=TRUE),
       data=dd,
       auto.key=list(space="right", title="No. Red", cex.title=1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! can you or someone else tell me how to code the data in the form shown above? how do I get the 1L, 1L, 0L, etc ?

Comment: See `import.csv` to import your file into R.  The L means only that it's an integer; `import.csv` will automatically decide how best to store it (the defaults can be changed if you like). mpitkas used `dput` to output the data in a way that could easily be used by others, but that's usually something you would do only to help others recreate your code.

Comment: @Aaron, you probably meant `read.csv`? Quick search on rseek.org did not return any hits for `import.csv`.

Comment: Yes, `read.csv`.  Thanks for the fix -- perhaps I was thinking about PROC IMPORT and got mixed up.